# position relative div shifting location slightly

Tags: css, html

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RPcYN/) is a JSFiddle that (for me) shows the problem perfectly.

But, I have several divs that load dynamically with images within them, then I have a transparent div over the top that will have some options, however the top div's location shifts funny when the image behind fully loads.

ANy idea on how to prevent this?

Here is the relevant code:
**HTML:**

```
<div id="img">
<img src="http://tbremer.com/images/portfolio/Concert/_MG_6961.jpg" height="200">                        <div id="imgOver">test</div>
</div>

<div id="img">
<img src="http://tbremer.com/images/portfolio/Concert/_MG_6964.jpg" height="200">                        <div id="imgOver">test</div>
</div>

<div id="img">
&nbsp;<img src="http://tbremer.com/images/portfolio/Concert/_MG_7063.jpg" width="200">&nbsp;
<div id="imgOver">test</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#img{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;

    background-color: rgb(232, 227, 223);
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#imgOver{
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);    
    color: #fff;
}
​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do is like this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RPcYN/1/)

[**Full Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RPcYN/2/)

Explanation :
What you've to do is use `position: relative;` for `img` and than use `position: absolute;` for `#imgOver` and remove `top: -200px`

HTML

```
<div id="img">                       
    <img src="http://tbremer.com/images/portfolio/Concert/_MG_6961.jpg" height="200">  
<div id="imgOver">test</div>     
</div>
```

CSS

```
#img{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgb(232, 227, 223);
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#imgOver{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);    
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This. Works. Perfect. Thank you so much!

Would you mind explaining why it works so well though?

Comment: @tbremer I've explained you but if you want will explain you once again, giving `position: relative;` to your container div will restrict any `position: absolute;` div to flow out of that container, so I gave `position: absolute;` to `#imgOver` and `top: 0;`